# Building installation package with service credentials in it

Tags: wix, credentials, azure-devops, dotnetinstaller

I am using wix/dotnetinstaller to install a windows service. The service will need to run under a non system account that is set up by the user. Is it possible to build installation package with credential included ? Whole idea is to preparing package when user ( after login to his web panel ) click download button. Generated package should have credential included and after installation there won't be necessary to put it again.

Answer (score 0):

As you no doubt know it is not advisable to run a service with user credentials for security reasons and maintainability alike. However, if you use **Windows Installer** you can input the service credentials during installation or set them on the command line like this:

```
msiexec.exe /I "C:\Test.msi" /QN /L* "C:\Tmp\msilog.log" USERNAME="Test" PASSWORD="Test"
```

You then author the **ServiceInstall** and **ServiceControl** tables in the MSI file to install and configure the service using the properties **USERNAME** and **PASSWORD** for StartName and Password columns respectively.

I would recommend using WIX for this - which is a free tool capable of compiling MSI binaries from XML source files. For a crash course in WIX I recommend these two sources:

1. [Simple "get going" sample from Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/105638/A-quick-introduction-Create-an-MSI-installer-with)
2. [Full blown WIX tutorial](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial)

If you are a "tinkerer" these two sources - particularly the first one - will help you get going pretty fast using WIX.

You can also use more higher level tools with better GUI and some "automagic" such as [Installshield](http://www.installshield.com/) and [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/).

Comment: THX for fast answer but I think my question was a little bit imprecise. My application works as a windows service (client – server)  and every user got his own account. I want be able to prepare for him, installation package with his credential included, not windows user credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can't do that because to start a service with the user's credentials you'll need the user's password, and you can't get hold of it.  Why does this process you're running need to be a service? You could create it as an ordinary process and have it in the Startup menu of the user, then it will start when the user logs on.